Talkie Library/Speech synthesis options for Raspberry Pi Zero
I am porting my Arduino sketch from Arduino Uno to Raspberry Pi 2040 zero (the blue board that is about postage stamp sized). It uses the talkie library here.
https://github.com/ArminJo/Talkie
But the above talkie library is not supported on Raspberry Pi 2040 zero. Is there a similar alternative speech synthesis library for Raspberry Pi 2040 zero? Or a substitute speech library for Raspberry Pi 2040 zero? A speech library that will fit into a stock unmodified Raspberry Pi 2040 board.

@jsotola It is  obviously a  reasonable question to ask on an Arduino

@jsotola Site.To answer your question the Raspberry Pi board can be programmed as Arduino through the Arduino ide e.g. as done in this youtube video here for examplr https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0ro3TPzbwA

I don't know why people think it's off topic. Despite you indicating otherwise, maybe they think you're talking about the RPI Zero, as in the thing more related to a full sized Raspberry Pi (the SBC) and not something which is in fact closer to an RPI Pico (the dual cortex-m0 based thing) or Arduino NANO RP2040 Connect to take a official example. Anyway, it's a question about an Arduino library being supported/replaced when moving to another board supported by the IDE and build system. This should not a problem for this site.

@chez, If you are "porting", maybe try to port the library, there is not much porting need for the Arduino sketch as the API for different boards are very much the same. The library already supports ARM Cortex-M0 (such as SAMD, Teensy), and ARM Cortex-M3 (blue pill), both are similar to Pico RP2040, probably changes are the timer to be used and pin(s) for the PWM output.

Maybe provide a link to (or picture) of the "blue board that is about postage stamp sized" so that it is really clear what you're talking about.

Talkie is for Arduino. For RPI zero, use PicoTTS or ESPeak-NG. https://github.com/ihuguet/picotts
https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng
If you later want to switch to any other Chip, you can try ADAM-Speech-Synthesizer based on the SPO256A-AL2 chip.
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/ADAM_Speech_Synthesizer_ae73d03e.html
